# How to recognize comment char in url?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have link (link created in external source):

```
http://mysite/something/?#var_1=something
```

but django get only:

```
http://mysite/something/?
```

How to get var_1?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not send anything after the # to the server. There's nothing you can do about that if you're using a normal link; the only way would be to use Javascript to send it.